# How to send the values of multi select box to django backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, django, django-views

https://select2.github.io/examples.html
See the multiple select. 
How do i send the multiple values from the select to django backend?

Comment: your question is not entirely clear can  you provide some details, maybe some code and what you are attempting to do

Comment: ok. i found this one https://select2.github.io/examples.html   how do i send the selected values to django backend as post request?

Comment: your question is too wide. You are basically asking for someone to build out your application.

Comment: I sorry for that. i found a way to do multiple select. I just want to know how to send the values of selected options in multiselect field to backend. thats all i need

Comment: This is a really incomplete question; Please update your question and show what you're actually trying to do. Explain what will be stored in the Select2, explain how you're posting back to the server (form post or ajax), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is incredibly sparse (fix that, please) so I'm going to have to make a few assumptions.

Select2 is just a wrapper around a real `<select>`. This means it works exactly like any other select box would in a form. So if you use a Django `Form` object, you can set it up with a `MultipleChoiceField`.

```
from django import forms

class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    COUNTRIES = (
        ('AUT', 'Austria'),
        ('DEU', 'Germany'),
        ('NLD', 'Neitherlands'),
    )

    countries = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=COUNTRIES)
```

Then, when your form is submitted, Django will handle the multiple options selected by feeding your `POST` data to that form in the view.

```
def update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get POST data from the request so it can be validated in your form object
        form = CountryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something with the data
```